# Matlab HOF to apply a function to every row of a matrix

Tags: matlab, higher-order-functions

I am trying to write a MATLAB function that applies a function to every row of a matrix. Is there a function that does this already? Stack overflow didn't seem to turn up anything. If not, here is the function I am trying to write:

```
function Z = rowMap(f,X)
[m n] = shape(Z);
Y = [];
for i = 1:m
  Y = [Y f(X(i,:))];
end
Z = Y;
end
```

Does MATLAB support higher order functions like this? I get an unexpected matlab operator error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a function called rowfun which works on tables.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with the code you've provided.
1st your function returns Z, so you can not pass it at the beginning of the function to the `shape` function. Also, I'm not sure what the shape function is as it is not a built in MATLAB function. My guess is you want the `size` function.

You have complex indexing scheme going on. Unless the elements of X contain values that are indexes of the elements of f you are going to get an error. I've re-written your code applying MATLAB's mean function to each row.

```
mat = [1 2 14 6 5 48 96 175;...
   1 2 5 6 7 45 65 45];
[m, n] = size(mat);
Y=[];
for i =1 :m
   Y = [Y,mean(mat(i,:))];
end
Z = Y;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write higher-order functions in MATLAB. This requires [function handles](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/function-handles.html).

You create a function handle using the `@` operator. For example, `@mean` is a handle to the function `mean`. You can also create [anonymous functions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) (in other languages called lambdas), which can capture variables. For example,

```
data = rand(50,1);
func = @(ii)mean(data.^ii);
```

creates a function handle `func` that you can pass to a function and contains `data`.

Your `rowMap` function then can be written as

```
function Y = rowMap(f, X)
m = size(X, 1);
Y = zeros(m,1);
for i = 1:m
  Y(i) = f(X(i,:));
end
```

and be called with

```
X = randn(50, 50);
Y = rowMap(@mean, X);
```

or, using the function handle `func` we created above,

```
Y = rowMap(func, X);
```

(Do note that this is the same as calling `Y = mean(X, 2)`, a lot of MATLAB functions work along one dimension only.)